# Install disk isn't finishing

Tags: 10.10, installation

So I have tried installing ubuntu 10.10 on an empty hard drive and I will get all the way to the slide show and after some time it goes to a screen with vertical lines on it kinda like it is stalling out and nothing happens after words.

I was successful in getting all the way to the menu that say's it must restart and went to restart it and it said there was no disk I even went to the boot menu and selected the appropriate drive to boot from thinking maybe it had something to do with that.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post what hardware your installing Ubuntu on? My best guess would be a incompatible hardware, or a corrupted install disk. Try re-downloading and re-burning the install disk (unless your booting from flash drive re-download and re-apply the iso to the flash drive).

Comment: I recently experienced exactly this and it was because my disc was dirty.  At least I think that was the problem.  I couldn't see anything on the disc, but I cleaned it anyway and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the disc before choosing the restart option, then you might not be able to restart from the desktop, in which case you have to manually turn off and turn on your computer and it should boot fine if your BIOS is set right.

If you chose to restart while the disc is still in the drive, then either the disc will eject automatically or you will be prompted to eject it manually, after which it will restart.

The stalling out you mentioned may not be a problem since you already got to the restart screen. However, if that is the issue, it is possible that your disc is dirty, or that your drive can only read CD/DVD of a certain specification but you used one with another specification.